# Google Places API get establishment name

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using Google places API for autocomplete.  I'm using this example, which I modified to be able to search by business name not only the address.

[example code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)

```
function initAutocomplete() {
                var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
                var options = {                    
                    types: ['geocode', 'establishment']
                };
                autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

                autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);

            };
```

So my question is, is it possible to get the business name, if the search is made not by address but by name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to get the name, it is returned in the [PlaceResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult) object returned by the `getPlace()` call:

```
document.getElementById("business").value = place.name;
document.getElementById("business").disabled = false;
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ep5aw171/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};



// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
</style> <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500"> <style> #locationField,
#controls {
  position: relative;
  width: 480px;
}
#autocomplete {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 99%;
}
.label {
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  color: #303030;
}
#address {
  border: 1px solid #000090;
  background-color: #f0f0ff;
  width: 480px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}
#address td {
  font-size: 10pt;
}
.field {
  width: 99%;
}
.slimField {
  width: 80px;
}
.wideField {
  width: 200px;
}
#locationField {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="locationField">
  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" />
</div>

<table id="address">
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Name</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
      <input class="field" id="business" disabled="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Street address</td>
    <td class="slimField">
      <input class="field" id="street_number" disabled="true" />
    </td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="2">
      <input class="field" id="route" disabled="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">City</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
      <input class="field" id="locality" disabled="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">State</td>
    <td class="slimField">
      <input class="field" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true" />
    </td>
    <td class="label">Zip code</td>
    <td class="wideField">
      <input class="field" id="postal_code" disabled="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Country</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
      <input class="field" id="country" disabled="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script>
  function initAutocomplete() {
    var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
    var options = {
      types: ['geocode', 'establishment']
    };
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);

  };

  function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }
    document.getElementById("business").value = place.name;
    document.getElementById("business").disabled = false;
    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm[addressType]) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
        document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Additional to this, is there anyway to check if its an address or business name? Because if the address is entered, the street name becomes places_name..